# adding annotation_ticks within one of two facets in ggplot2

Tags: r

Is it possible to add ticks to only one side of the facet using `annotation_ticks`? this command adds ticks to both of my facets. I used `facet_wrap` to show data from the year 2020 and 2021 and only want the ticks on the left 2020 facet

```
annotation_logticks(base = 10,
                        sides = "l",
                        outside = TRUE,
                        long = unit(0.1, "cm"))
```

Comment: I think this is a property of the axis which is linked to the logticks. You can create multiple plots and combine them e.g. using patchwork

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I have done this however found the ggplot2 facet_wrap() nicer as it uses the same scale for each facet. I would just want the ticks to appear once on the left instead of twice but if this is not possible i will have to find a different solution

Answer (score 0):

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(patchwork)

iris %>%
  nest(-Species) %>%
  mutate(
    do_logticks = row_number() == 1,
    plt = data %>% map2(do_logticks, ~{
      plt <- qplot(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, data = .x)
      if(.y) {
        plt <- plt + annotation_logticks(sides = "l")
      }
      plt
    })
  ) %>%
  pull(plt) %>%
  wrap_plots(nrow = 1)
#> Warning: All elements of `...` must be named.
#> Did you want `data = c(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, Petal.Length, Petal.Width)`?
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-10-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>